# why its output is worng?

Tags: python, python-3.x

can anybody explain why this output is worng
because i make the output as such in the question
but it shows output is incorrect
like this  Not quite. How are you deciding which part of the address is
the house number and which is the street name? Are you
removing any trailing blank spaces? Properly formatting the
return string?

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  num=" "
  cha=" "

  # Separate the address string into parts
  address_string=address_string.split()
  
  for text in address_string:
      if text.isdigit():
          num=text
      else:
          cha += text +" "
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(num,cha) 

    

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

my output

```
house number 123 on street named  Main Street 
house number 1001 on street named  1st Ave 
house number 55 on street named  North Center Drive
```

Comment: your output seems exactly like the output you expect except for one extra space after "named". Is this extra space what you are asking for?

Comment: You initialize `cha=" "` with a leading space.

Comment: what if you live in "123b Main Street"?

Comment: thank you every one i got it

Answer (score 0):

If the address format is always house number followed by the remainder of the address then this might be a better approach:

```
def format_address(address_string):
    tokens = address_string.split()
    return f'House number {tokens[0]} on street named {" ".join(tokens[1:])}'

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
```

**Output:**

```
House number 123 on street named Main Street
House number 1001 on street named 1st Ave
House number 55 on street named North Center Drive
```